Removing underlayment from asbestos tile
We are renovating our bathroom/laundry room in a 50's ranch built on a slab foundation. Previous owners installed a floating laminate click lock floor, which disintegrated due to the movement of washer dryer. We are left with a foam underlayment adhered to presumed asbestos tile (right age, look and dimensions).
Do I need to remove this underlayment, edit in order to encapsulate? If so, how?
Ideally I would like to encapsulate the tile and lay flooring over top. Flooring will likely be glue down or adhesive backed marmoleum tile or similar. Is there a encapsulation method you'd recommend?

Only a lab test will confirm asbestos. However best not to disturb it.  I would cover with LVP or LVT with solid core.  if the flooring is installed properly it is waterproof and will not allow anything underneath to filter through , making the room safe.  No need to glue down, A completed floor will work well with a washer and dryer that are functioning properly.

The washer and dryer are what make it necessary to glue down the new flooring. The old flooring broke apart, starting mainly in front of the dryer. The same floor is installed in our kitchen, and is doing fine.

That's why I included "functioning properly"   A washer and dryer that are functioning properly will not impact a floor because of leaks, vibrations, heat or any other reason.   If the washer and dryer are dripping water, vibrating too much or giving off too much heat, you need to fix that problem.   I have 5 rental units with W&D on LVP and never had any issues.
